# Why android gives error when we write getApplicationContext() as a perameter in AlertDialog.Builder.?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I just want to know why android gives error when we write

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

whether it is right. and why it only works when we put `this` as a perameter.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: try replace getApplicationContext() by  object of context

Comment: answer to your question can be found [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326366/what-context-should-i-use-alertdialog-builder-in

Comment: I am asking for the concept why the use of getApplicationContext() gives error in AlertDialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application` is a global object and so is it's `Context`. Application context should be used only for things that need a `Context` that is not tied to the currently running component, like an `Activity`.

In this case, the `AlertDialog` is created inside the `Activity` (i assume) and it needs the context of only that `Activity` - hence you should use `this`. The reasoning is that `AlertDialog` does not have a life outside of its parent `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for this simple and perfect answer.